# Error log of make command in Linux

Tags: makefile, compilation

I am compiling a kernel module and it has many compilation errors in it. After running "make", the errors thrown out are too many to fit in the screen. Scrolling up doesn't reach the first error. I tried capturing the errors by doing *make &2 > log* which didn't work (log file was empty and the error messages were still dumped on screen).

Can someone please tell me how to go about logging all the messages generated during compilation/make into a logfile?

Comment: @PaulR How can it be that you put the ampersand before, and Nathan Fellman puts it after?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: it depends on what shell you are using - the comment above assumes bash, but syntax differs between different shells

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try doing:

```
make >&log
```

the `&` after the `>` tells the shell to dump both stdout and stderr to the `log`.  This can also be used with pipes.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to watch it scroll past, too:

```
 make 2>&1 | tee log
```

(/bin/sh, bash and related) This sends the standard error to the same place as the standard output, then pipes them through tee to capture the result and still get screen action.

Comment: Your example is analogous to: make 2>&1 > log , right?